# @mui grid items of equal height

Tags: material-ui, css-grid

Using the React @mui package, I want to create a grid of items that all stretch to the same height as the tallest item. I've tried searching for similar questions but have not found a working solution, and using @mui v5. Here's my example, also found on Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-moon-y5lugj?file=/src/App.js. I prefer a solution (if possible) using the @mui components rather than grid css directly. Also I cannot fix the number of columns, it needs to be responsive.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Card,
  Container,
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  Typography
} from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const createTable = (rows) => {
    return (
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          {[...Array(rows).keys()].map((n) => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={n}>
                <TableCell>Aaaaa</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Box p={3}>
      <Container maxWidth="sm" height="100%">
        <Grid container spacing={2} height="100%">
          <Grid item height="100%">
            <Paper height="100%" elevation={3} sx={{ p: 3 }}>
              <Typography variant="h4">Something</Typography>
              {createTable(5)}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item height="100%">
            <Paper height="100%" elevation={3} sx={{ p: 3 }}>
              <Typography variant="h4">More things</Typography>
              {createTable(3)}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is what I get now. I want the shorter item to be padded on the bottom so its the same height as the first.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this code from the box downwards. You can read more about how to work with grid items on the mui website [here](https://mui.com/components/grid/).

```
const StackOverflow = () => {
  const createTable = (rows) => {
    return (
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          {[...Array(rows).keys()].map((n) => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={n}>
                <TableCell>Aaaaa</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Box p={3}>
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ p: 3, height: "100%" }}>
              <Typography variant="h4">Something</Typography>
              {createTable(5)}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Paper elevation={3} sx={{ p: 3, height: "100%" }}>
              <Typography variant="h4">More things</Typography>
              {createTable(3)}
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Something that worked good for me was to use the following in the Papers sx prop:

```js
{{ height: "100%", display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
```

Comment: An alternative approach could be to add the styles to the using the "sx" property using "flex" for the display value and a "justifyContent" property with value "space-between" which stretches in the internal components to match the height.